# Dynamically accessing a field in ElasticSearch function score

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I've been trying to find a solution for this in the last couple of days but could not, so here is my question.

Basically we have some of the users most commonly used search keywords indexed in the documents that the user end up visiting. For example, If users' search "Football" a lot and end up going to document X, document X would have something like

```
keywords: {
     "football": some int boost value
}
```

I want to check after the user searches using a keyword Y if in the retrieved documents, the field 'keywords.Y' exists, if it does, I would use function score to multiply Y by _score if not, I will just return the _score.

Is that even possible? And here is what I have built so far.

```
{
"size": "20",
"from": "0",
"sort": [],
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "fields": [
                                        "cuisines.name.en^8",
                                        "cuisines.name.ar^8"
                                    ],
                                    "query": "+mori",
                                    "use_dis_max": true,
                                    "default_operator": "and"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "fuzzy_like_this_field": {
                                    "name.en": {
                                        "like_text": "mori",
                                        "boost": 15,
                                        "min_similarity": 0.6
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "flag": 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "cityID": "1000"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "script_score": {
                    "params": {
                        "q": "mori"
                    },
                    "script": "_score;"
                }
            }
        ],
        "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
```

}

So basically here, I want to access the field, keywords.mori. Sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this might be helpful to anyone, but I ended up using the exists filter to give an additional score to documents that have the search keywords in it.

```
                                "constant_score": {
                                    "filter": {
                                        "exists": {"field": k},
                                     }
                                 }
```

Where k is equal to 'keywords.{searched_keyword}'